# How to run a for loop involving objects that are entangled in ajax and jquery scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, for-loop

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("json_encode.php", function (data) {
            var user_data = '';
            var rowcounter = 0;
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                rowcounter++;
                user_data += '<tr>';
                user_data += '<td>' + value.first_name + '</td>';
                user_data += '<td>' + value.last_name + '</td>';
                user_data += '<td>' + value.telephone_number + '</td>';
                user_data += '<td>' + value.street + '</td>';
                user_data += '<td>' + value.city + '</td>';
                user_data += '<td>' + value.state + '</td>';
                user_data += '<td>' + value.zip_code + '</td>';
                user_data += '<td>' + value.email_address + '</td>';
                user_data += '<td><input type="submit" id="delete' + rowcounter + '" value="Delete" align="center"></td>';
                user_data += '<td><input type="submit" id="edit' + rowcounter + '" value="Edit" align="center"></td>';
                user_data += '</tr>';
            });
            $('#user_table').append(user_data);
        });
    });

    for(var i=1, l = $(document).id("user_data").length; i <= l; i++){
        $(document).on('click', "#delete" + i, function () {
            alert('i');
    });

</script>
```

---

The code creates a table with 10 columns. The last two columns create two columns of "delete" and "edit" buttons. These buttons, when clicked, is supposed to delete or edit the row they are in.

Right now, I'm trying to run a for loop to spit out the number of the row the "delete" button is clicked but I can't seem to make the for loop script runnable.

For example, if I click the delete button on the first row, he id of it would be "delete1" as having made my id code being (id="delete' + rowcounter + '").

I want to print out the value of "i" through alert which would be the number of the row.

Comment: let i and alert(i)

Answer (score 0):

assuming data is an array, do this:

```
        data.forEach(function (value, index) {
            rowcounter++;
            user_data += '<tr>';
            user_data += '<td>' + value.first_name + '</td>';
            user_data += '<td>' + value.last_name + '</td>';
            user_data += '<td>' + value.telephone_number + '</td>';
            user_data += '<td>' + value.street + '</td>';
            user_data += '<td>' + value.city + '</td>';
            user_data += '<td>' + value.state + '</td>';
            user_data += '<td>' + value.zip_code + '</td>';
            user_data += '<td>' + value.email_address + '</td>';
            user_data += '<td><input type="submit" id="delete' + index + '" value="Delete" align="center"></td>';
            user_data += '<td><input type="submit" id="edit' + index + '" value="Edit" align="center"></td>';
            user_data += '</tr>';
        });
```

Comment: and then add a few hundred listeners :/... use delete and edit as a class, just assign index to the id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("json_encode.php", function (data) {
      var user_data = ''
      $.each(data, function (value, key) {
        user_data += '<tr>'
        user_data += '<td>' + value.first_name + '</td>'
        user_data += '<td>' + value.last_name + '</td>'
        user_data += '<td>' + value.telephone_number + '</td>'
        user_data += '<td>' + value.street + '</td>'
        user_data += '<td>' + value.city + '</td>'
        user_data += '<td>' + value.state + '</td>'
        user_data += '<td>' + value.zip_code + '</td>'
        user_data += '<td>' + value.email_address + '</td>'
        user_data += '<td><input type="submit" id="delete' + key + '" value="Delete" align="center"></td>'
        user_data += '<td><input type="submit" id="edit' + key + '" value="Edit" align="center"></td>'
        user_data += '</tr>'
      })
      $('#user_table').append(user_data)
    })
  })

  $(document).on('click', '[id|="delete"]', function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove()
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow thank you for your prompt replies. I ended up just storing the row number in the id and then pulling up the id name as a substring.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.getJSON("json_encode.php", function (data) {
                var user_data = '';
                var rowcounter = 0;
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    rowcounter++;
                    user_data += '<tr>';
                    user_data += '<td>' + value.first_name + '</td>';
                    user_data += '<td>' + value.last_name + '</td>';
                    user_data += '<td>' + value.telephone_number + '</td>';
                    user_data += '<td>' + value.street + '</td>';
                    user_data += '<td>' + value.city + '</td>';
                    user_data += '<td>' + value.state + '</td>';
                    user_data += '<td>' + value.zip_code + '</td>';
                    user_data += '<td>' + value.email_address + '</td>';
                    user_data += '<td><button type="submit" id="delete' + rowcounter + '" value="" align="center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> Delete</span></button></td>';
                    user_data += '<td><button type="submit" id="edit' + rowcounter + '" value="" align="center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> Edit</button></td>';
                    user_data += '</tr>';
                });
                $('#user_table').append(user_data);
                for(var i=1, l =$(user_data).length; i <= l; i++){
                    $(document).on('click', "#delete" + i, function () {
                        var val=this.id;
                        var delete_index = val.substring(6,8);
                        alert(delete_index);
                    });
                    $(document).on('click', "#edit" + i, function (){
                        var val=this.id;
                        var edit_index = val.substring(4,6);
                        alert(edit_index);
                    })
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```